# Migrating older Visual Studio solutions to 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, migration

I'm working on an application that contains nearly 300 solutions from Visual Studio 2005 to 2012. Now I've to migrate all these solutions to Visual Studio 2013. Is there any tool available that scans all the older solutions in the application folder recursively and migrate the potential ones to 2013? If not then I'm ready to write a small utility but I'm not sure where to start. Could someone provide some guidance to achieve that?

Comment: Have you tried isting all *.vcproj and calling VCUpgrade on them? VCUpgrade will ignore thos that are up-to-date already

Comment: Not yet. After googling I found there is another command called devenv.exe /upgrade. Not sure about the differences between these two.

Comment: Some info here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/03/25/to-the-command-line-enthusiasts-some-quick-know-hows-for-upgrading-to-vs-2010.aspx